# Android Naming Layout Scheme

Tags: android

I have a piece of code

```
public class Radio_groupActivity extends ListActivity {
TextView selection;
String[] items={"One", "Two", "Three"};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1));

}
```

}

Now I have the main.xml in the folder but I don't have any xml file called simple_list_item_1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>


<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/selection"
/>


<ListView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/list" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

So, what's the relationship of the listview with @id/list and that android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `android.` package qualifier in `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` means you're referring to an Android framework resource rather than a resource from your app. You may not have a layout by that name, but the Android framework does.

ListActivity looks for a ListView with the id `@android:id/list` when using `setListAdapter`.

Comment: but the setListAdapter only mentions simple_list_item_1 it didn't mention @id/List at all.

Comment: It doesn't have to. `@android:id/list` is defined by the framework, it's already known to ListActivity.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId)

android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 is system built-in text view for list item displaying

Comment: but the setListAdapter only mentions simple_list_item_1 it didn't mention @id/List at all.

Comment: adamp already answered you. This ListActivity will lookup ListView with id list as its ListView.